# Drupal query builder return all fields

Tags: php, drupal-7, query-builder

How do I write a query using Drupal 7's query builder to return all the fields (SELECT *), not just the ones I specify through ->fields.

Edit:
I tried something like

> $query = db_select('table')
>   ->condition('id', 2);

but when i echo it it's something like:

> SELECT  FROM  {table} table WHERE  (id =
>   :db_condition_placeholder_0)

I haven't tested the query but my thoughts are the it will not work cause there is no * after SELECT.

Comment: Googling would have helped. https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!database.inc/function/db_query/7

Comment: I already searched (your link included), and I haven't found how to accomplish such a feat.

Comment: Can you post what you've tried so far?

Comment: short answer: `$id = 1; $results = db_query('SELECT * FROM table WHERE someId = :myId', array(':myId' => $id));`

Comment: Edited what i tried out. I don't like your solution because I don't know how many fields I will have in my contion statement (WHERE) and my code will look ugly and hard to understand if i just concatenate strings toghether.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is how you do it:

```
<?php

$myId = 5;
$result = db_select('table', 't')
    ->fields('t')
    ->condition('id', $myId, '=')
    ->execute()
    ->fetchAssoc();

?>
```

the above is equivelent to:

`SELECT t.* FROM table as t WHERE t.id = 7`

More info is on the API documentation found here: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!database.inc/function/db_select/7